# 416 from cloudfront when S3 origin video/mp4 resource replaced with bigger file

Tags: caching, video, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Why is cloudfront responding with a 416 status in the following scenario, even though I *believe* the requested range *should* be satisfiable?

## Original S3 object

The scenario:

1. configure cloudfront distribution with an S3 origin, Object Caching set to "Customize", min/max/default TTL all set to 0
2. upload a video/mp4 file to S3, with no cache related headers set
3. playback video in chrome, via cloudfront

At this point, everything seems fine. I see 3 network requests to the resource - why chrome is requesting overlapping ranges in 2 and 3, I don't understand, but nevertheless, the video plays fine at this point.

## Overwritten S3 object

Now, soon after:

1. upload larger (~ 2x) file to same S3 location
2. playback video in chrome, via cloudfront

This time, an error occurs.

It seems as though resp 1 here is ok (i.e. content length looks to be correct) - although not sure why it's a `Miss from cloudfront` - I would've expected it to be a `RefreshHit` given the TTL settings

**Why is "req 2" of second page load failing with a 416, even though the requested range is within the content length from resp 1?**

Notes:

- going direct to S3, there is no problem
- replacing the bigger file back to the smaller file, the video plays fine again
- uploading the file to S3 with "cache-control: no-cache", there is no problem but I always get a "Miss from cloudfront". My understanding is that cloudfront should always be checking with S3 to see if content has changed with this configuration
- waiting for some time (say 30s) - the problem resolves itself
- previous attempts at replicating this scenario saw an addition 304 response from S3 to CloudFront after the overwrite, but I haven't been able to replicate that exact behaviour (there is just a single 216 now)

---

## Logs

### Original S3 object

#### Chrome

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498631683",
    "response_status": 206,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": ":path", "value": "/video.mp4?u=1481498631683" },
      { "name": "pragma", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": "accept-encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" },
      { "name": "accept-language", "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,id;q=0.4" },
      { "name": "user-agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "accept", "value": "*/*" },
      { "name": "cache-control", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": ":authority", "value": "dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net" },
      { "name": ":scheme", "value": "https" },
      { "name": "range", "value": "bytes=0-" },
      { "name": ":method", "value": "GET" }
    ],
    "response_headers": [
      { "name": "date", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:54 GMT" },
      { "name": "via", "value": "1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" },
      { "name": "last-modified", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:45 GMT" },
      { "name": "server", "value": "AmazonS3" },
      { "name": "etag", "value": "\"4ab3cf8dcd7747d45c1723eb19c0c7fa\"" },
      { "name": "status", "value": "206" },
      { "name": "x-cache", "value": "Miss from cloudfront" },
      { "name": "content-type", "value": "video/mp4" },
      { "name": "content-range", "value": "bytes 0-535350/535351" },
      { "name": "accept-ranges", "value": "bytes" },
      { "name": "content-length", "value": "535351" },
      { "name": "x-amz-cf-id", "value": "-6zzzNwipKKtO_L-vU3o4dbH30cBHV2zu-28rZXwVrZm5uI8oKADYw==" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498631683",
    "response_status": 206,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": ":path", "value": "/video.mp4?u=1481498631683" },
      { "name": "pragma", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": "accept-encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" },
      { "name": "accept-language", "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,id;q=0.4" },
      { "name": "user-agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "accept", "value": "*/*" },
      { "name": "cache-control", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": ":authority", "value": "dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net" },
      { "name": ":scheme", "value": "https" },
      { "name": "if-match", "value": "\"4ab3cf8dcd7747d45c1723eb19c0c7fa\"" },
      { "name": "range", "value": "bytes=524288-" },
      { "name": ":method", "value": "GET" }
    ],
    "response_headers": [
      { "name": "date", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:54 GMT" },
      { "name": "via", "value": "1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" },
      { "name": "last-modified", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:45 GMT" },
      { "name": "server", "value": "AmazonS3" },
      { "name": "etag", "value": "\"4ab3cf8dcd7747d45c1723eb19c0c7fa\"" },
      { "name": "status", "value": "206" },
      { "name": "x-cache", "value": "RefreshHit from cloudfront" },
      { "name": "content-type", "value": "video/mp4" },
      { "name": "content-range", "value": "bytes 524288-535350/535351" },
      { "name": "accept-ranges", "value": "bytes" },
      { "name": "content-length", "value": "11063" },
      { "name": "x-amz-cf-id", "value": "_z3F_A7pVXHz5PBulj8-4OeRolEzWdgT9R4-JdvgUpTLq463MZ-C_A==" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498631683",
    "response_status": 206,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": ":path", "value": "/video.mp4?u=1481498631683" },
      { "name": "pragma", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": "accept-encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" },
      { "name": "accept-language", "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,id;q=0.4" },
      { "name": "user-agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "accept", "value": "*/*" },
      { "name": "cache-control", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": ":authority", "value": "dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net" },
      { "name": ":scheme", "value": "https" },
      { "name": "if-match", "value": "\"4ab3cf8dcd7747d45c1723eb19c0c7fa\"" },
      { "name": "range", "value": "bytes=32768-" },
      { "name": ":method", "value": "GET" }
    ],
    "response_headers": [
      { "name": "date", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:54 GMT" },
      { "name": "via", "value": "1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" },
      { "name": "last-modified", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:23:45 GMT" },
      { "name": "server", "value": "AmazonS3" },
      { "name": "etag", "value": "\"4ab3cf8dcd7747d45c1723eb19c0c7fa\"" },
      { "name": "status", "value": "206" },
      { "name": "x-cache", "value": "RefreshHit from cloudfront" },
      { "name": "content-type", "value": "video/mp4" },
      { "name": "content-range", "value": "bytes 32768-535350/535351" },
      { "name": "accept-ranges", "value": "bytes" },
      { "name": "content-length", "value": "502583" },
      { "name": "x-amz-cf-id", "value": "8MGICqcddKwl5HZ2sNN6fpTSwO1I8qkvvurVfbBftlikXKdi-FQhdQ==" }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Cloudfront

```
#Fields: date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) x-edge-result-type x-edge-request-id x-host-header cs-protocol cs-bytes time-taken x-forwarded-for ssl-protocol ssl-cipher x-edge-response-result-type cs-protocol-version
2016-12-11      23:23:53        MEL50   34771   150.101.108.33  GET     dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    /video.mp4      206     -       Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_12_1)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/55.0.2883.87%2520Safari/537.36        u=1481498631683 -       Error   -6zzzNwipKKtO_L-vU3o4dbH30cBHV2zu-28rZXwVrZm5uI8oKADYw==        dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    https   46      1.613   -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     Miss    HTTP/2.0
2016-12-11      23:23:56        MEL50   11408   150.101.108.33  GET     dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    /video.mp4      206     -       Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_12_1)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/55.0.2883.87%2520Safari/537.36        u=1481498631683 -       RefreshHit      _z3F_A7pVXHz5PBulj8-4OeRolEzWdgT9R4-JdvgUpTLq463MZ-C_A==        dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    https   47      2.194   -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     RefreshHit      HTTP/2.0
2016-12-11      23:23:56        MEL50   503468  150.101.108.33  GET     dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    /video.mp4      206     -       Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_12_1)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/55.0.2883.87%2520Safari/537.36        u=1481498631683 -       RefreshHit      8MGICqcddKwl5HZ2sNN6fpTSwO1I8qkvvurVfbBftlikXKdi-FQhdQ==        dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    https   47      0.259   -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     RefreshHit      HTTP/2.0
```

#### S3

```
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:23:44 +0000] 150.101.108.33 arn:aws:iam::<IAM ID>:user/<username> FB18FDABAA5DF6CA REST.PUT.OBJECT video.mp4 "PUT /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 535351 6448 118 "-" "aws-cli/1.9.11 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.1.0 botocore/1.4.26" -
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:23:53 +0000] 54.239.202.78 - 934DB75AC20953C3 REST.GET.OBJECT video.mp4 "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 - 535351 535351 101 98 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" -
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:23:54 +0000] 54.239.202.78 - 56EF7496F985D4B3 REST.GET.OBJECT video.mp4 "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 304 - - 535351 11 - "-" "Amazon CloudFront" -
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:23:56 +0000] 54.239.202.78 - 7F0087B4769D0FD3 REST.GET.OBJECT video.mp4 "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 304 - - 535351 4 - "-" "Amazon CloudFront" -
```

### Overwritten S3 object

#### Chrome

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498656967",
    "response_status": 206,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": ":path", "value": "/video.mp4?u=1481498656967" },
      { "name": "pragma", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": "accept-encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" },
      { "name": "accept-language", "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,id;q=0.4" },
      { "name": "user-agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "accept", "value": "*/*" },
      { "name": "cache-control", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": ":authority", "value": "dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net" },
      { "name": ":scheme", "value": "https" },
      { "name": "range", "value": "bytes=0-" },
      { "name": ":method", "value": "GET" }
    ],
    "response_headers": [
      { "name": "date", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:24:19 GMT" },
      { "name": "via", "value": "1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" },
      { "name": "last-modified", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:24:07 GMT" },
      { "name": "server", "value": "AmazonS3" },
      { "name": "etag", "value": "\"d4d5776a96931962b41476857f34ab6d\"" },
      { "name": "status", "value": "206" },
      { "name": "x-cache", "value": "Miss from cloudfront" },
      { "name": "content-type", "value": "video/mp4" },
      { "name": "content-range", "value": "bytes 0-956851/956852" },
      { "name": "accept-ranges", "value": "bytes" },
      { "name": "content-length", "value": "956852" },
      { "name": "x-amz-cf-id", "value": "CjmlHAFcyEWCiV68Q0G3gltuQSV7maR5bUoX0CfngDgDBp5fDvI38A==" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498656967",
    "response_status": 416,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": ":path", "value": "/video.mp4?u=1481498656967" },
      { "name": "pragma", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": "accept-encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" },
      { "name": "accept-language", "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,id;q=0.4" },
      { "name": "user-agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "accept", "value": "*/*" },
      { "name": "cache-control", "value": "no-cache" },
      { "name": ":authority", "value": "dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net" },
      { "name": ":scheme", "value": "https" },
      { "name": "if-match", "value": "\"d4d5776a96931962b41476857f34ab6d\"" },
      { "name": "range", "value": "bytes=917504-" },
      { "name": ":method", "value": "GET" }
    ],
    "response_headers": [
      { "name": "date", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:24:19 GMT" },
      { "name": "via", "value": "1.1 0ea9662a9e73b2ca5836ede6924f81b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)" },
      { "name": "server", "value": "CloudFront" },
      { "name": "x-cache", "value": "Error from cloudfront" },
      { "name": "content-type", "value": "text/html" },
      { "name": "status", "value": "416" },
      { "name": "content-length", "value": "49" },
      { "name": "x-amz-cf-id", "value": "WIb50z_8rXTdqaC4CzUSYSL0kuIE9CWlCnKNgzps7AoCSRoJplBBbA==" },
      { "name": "expires", "value": "Sun, 11 Dec 2016 23:24:19 GMT" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net/video.mp4?u=1481498656967",
    "response_status": 0,
    "request_headers": [
      { "name": "User-Agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" },
      { "name": "Range", "value": "bytes=32768-" },
      { "name": "Accept-Encoding", "value": "identity;q=1, *;q=0" }
    ],
    "response_headers": []
  }
]
```

#### Cloudfront

```
#Fields: date time x-edge-location sc-bytes c-ip cs-method cs(Host) cs-uri-stem sc-status cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs-uri-query cs(Cookie) x-edge-result-type x-edge-request-id x-host-header cs-protocol cs-bytes time-taken x-forwarded-for ssl-protocol ssl-cipher x-edge-response-result-type cs-protocol-version
2016-12-11      23:24:19        MEL50   52198   150.101.108.33  GET     dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    /video.mp4      206     -       Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_12_1)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/55.0.2883.87%2520Safari/537.36        u=1481498656967 -       Error   CjmlHAFcyEWCiV68Q0G3gltuQSV7maR5bUoX0CfngDgDBp5fDvI38A==        dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    https   46      1.551   -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     Miss    HTTP/2.0
2016-12-11      23:24:19        MEL50   302     150.101.108.33  GET     dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    /video.mp4      416     -       Mozilla/5.0%2520(Macintosh;%2520Intel%2520Mac%2520OS%2520X%252010_12_1)%2520AppleWebKit/537.36%2520(KHTML,%2520like%2520Gecko)%2520Chrome/55.0.2883.87%2520Safari/537.36        u=1481498656967 -       Error   WIb50z_8rXTdqaC4CzUSYSL0kuIE9CWlCnKNgzps7AoCSRoJplBBbA==        dvayusv1lektq.cloudfront.net    https   47      0.001   -       TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     Error   HTTP/2.0
```

#### S3

```
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:24:06 +0000] 150.101.108.33 arn:aws:iam::<IAM ID>:user/<username> E58826B8A66DBA1B REST.PUT.OBJECT video.mp4 "PUT /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 956852 7367 53 "-" "aws-cli/1.9.11 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.1.0 botocore/1.4.26" -
8cd9b72de42431df1df4dadadab73aabf29ea0b34b5d821565fe4a16a3080509 bad-video-test [11/Dec/2016:23:24:18 +0000] 54.239.202.45 - BA1C06FEA7DAC83F REST.GET.OBJECT video.mp4 "GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 - 956852 956852 40 35 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" -
```

Comment: Logs updated so that they all come from same session.

Answer (score 2):

What you can't see is *which* object -- the old one or the new one -- S3 is serving to CloudFront on the first requests after the overwrite.

When you overwrite an existing object in S3, the overwrite is always an atomic operation, in the sense that every request will be satisfied with either the complete old object or the complete new object... but the timing is not guaranteed, because S3 has an eventual consistency model for overwrites of existing objects.

> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all regions.
>
> Updates to a single key are atomic. For example, if you PUT to an existing key, a subsequent read might return the old data or the updated data, but it will never write corrupted or partial data.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

Even if the bucket does not have versioning enabled, there's a window of time -- usually very short -- when both objects exist in S3.  It can't be any other way, given that the above statement is true.

Similarly, it's possible to request a nonexistent object from S3, then upload the object, then request it again and continue to get a 404 (or 403, depending on bucket configuration) response for a short time before downloads succeed.

Conversely, if there has never been an attempt to download a nonexistent object, you will always find it immediately available for download after you upload it.  This is a tradeoff that is essentially a design necesssity at large scale.

The bucket and distribution logs should help reveal what's happening behind the scenes, particularly if the CloudFront download from S3 on any of the download attempts after the upload shows a byte count consistent with the old object.

---

Upon further reflection... **there is a second possible explanation** what is happening, here, and it is difficult to decide whether or not this might be considered a bug in CloudFront, if indeed this is the actual issue.

After the object is replaced in S3, let's assume for a moment that consistency is **not** an issue -- let's assume thst all subsequent requests after the upload do in fact cause S3 to provide the current version of the object to CloudFront.

The problem here may be that the first download after the object was replaced -- which should have caused CloudFront to evict its old cached version of the object -- is being canceled by the browser.  (I've seen Chrome do this, though I don't know exactly why it does it.)

When a download is canceled, the response from the origin is **not** cached.

> **Canceled Requests**
>
> If an object is not in the edge cache, and if a viewer terminates a session (for example, closes a browser) after CloudFront gets the object from your origin but before it can deliver the requested object, CloudFront does not cache the object in the edge location.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html#response-s3-canceled-requests

Granted, this says "if the object is not in the edge cache," and you could argue that it actually is... but it may be a question of semantics: the object CloudFront is requesting from S3 is arguably *not* in the cache -- what's in the cache is a different object (at the same URI). If this logic holds, then the assertion that "CloudFront does not cache the object" presumably still holds, as well.

So... request 2 asks for a range outside of the range of the *old* object, which is the only thing CloudFront knows about.  CloudFront dutifully reports the fact that -- for all it knows -- the request is indeed out of bounds, requested range not satisfiable.

Arguably, CloudFront should verify that the object is fresh, first... but also arguably, the browser should not make a subsequent range request for an object it has never successfully downloaded.

Maybe we can shed some light on this with correlated log files.

Comment: Have added cloudfront logs to the question, will add S3 logs when they appear (I had to enable logging for the bucket).

Comment: If you look at the first response *after* the overwrite, it looks as though the edge location has the updated file to me (from `content length`) - it's unlikely that it will revert to the old version, given that it's the same edge location, isn't it?

Comment: That's a valid question, but in large-scale services, concepts of "the same" (edge, bucket, object, time, etc.) can have meanings that are less objective than they seem, when looking  To clarify a point, when you duplicate this with `curl`, you are not canceling any of the downloads -- you're letting them complete.  Is that right?  Also to clarify: I am not, at this point intending to assert that the behavior is necessarily correct or expected, but rather that there should be a concrete explanation which we need to uncover with more evidence.  What region is this bucket in?

Comment: What you assume about curl is correct, although I have removed the note from the question as the problem is not consistently repeatable with curl alone (so maybe cancelling the download has something to do with it).

Comment: Bucket is in `US Standard`.

Comment: The question has become quite long winded with all the logs and whatnot, and from two different session.  Let me know if it's worth editing it to make things clearer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a lengthy question, if the content is relevant and organized (it is), but I'd suggest that for clarity and thoroughness, we need just one set of logs, and they need to be correlatable between CF & S3 for the same set of requests. Chrome headers, too. I started to edit the answer yesterday to suggest that the canceled download is exactly the trigger and seeing the logs all together might be very valuable (and might be of particular value to AWS insiders who I know read SO) to help clarify that.  The older logs can be removed if we can get one clean, connected example.

Comment: Updated to add my thoughts on the canceled download scenario.

Comment: Just in the process of updating logs now - not a trivial task to format chrome logs in to something reasonable.

Comment: I *think* chrome makes the first request in each set, and then cancels, in order to get the overall length of the video (so that it can render controls appropriately, etc).  The alternative would be just to do a `HEAD`, which should give it the info it needs, but apparently server support for this is patchy, which is why it does it this way.

Comment: I definitely think you're on to something with the "second possible explanation" - i.e. the problem is to do with the cancelled download.